# Oracle DECODE vs. NVL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to analyze an existing Oracle query written by a departed developer. I'm not well versed in Oracle and I'm a bit confused by the use of this `DECODE` function in a `Microfocus COBOL` app (where `:BV-POS_YEAR` is a variable set to a year):

```
SELECT ...., DECODE(DELV_YEAR, NULL, :BV-POS_YEAR, DELV_YEAR), ....
```

I'm trying to understand how that would be different from:

```
SELECT ...., NVL(DELV_YEAR, :BV-POS_YEAR), ....
```

Am I misunderstanding something about the `DECODE` or `NVL` functions? The developer is aware of the NVL function as it is used elsewhere in the very same select statement.

Comment: It's the same; but might there once have been more clauses, say special handling for a magic year number like 9999? Or are the other `nvl` appearances for strings and the developer maybe thought it didn't work for numbers?

Comment: Thanks to both you and Michal for your responses. The code isn't very old. It's possible the developer saw specific non-null values as potentially having a different meaning in the future. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some aspect of `DECODE` or `NVL`.

Comment: I would advise you to use `COALESCE()`, because this is the ANSI standard version of the function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I'm not modifying the code. I'm merely trying to understand it so that we can port it to our new system (different language, different DBMS, different table structure). The new system is substantially different and this specific query will not exist in its current form in that system. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: I thought COBOL didn't overwrite non-null values with NULLs?

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure what you mean. This is really Oracle functions, not COBOL functionality. The only Oracle piece is the `:BV-POS_YEAR` variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NVL` replaces `NULL` by specified value.

`DECODE` replaces any specified value by desired value and can be chained. Your usage is equivalent, but `DECODE` has much wider usage. For example you can write this code

```
SELECT supplier_name,
DECODE(supplier_id, 10000, 'IBM',
                    10001, 'Microsoft',
                    10002, 'Hewlett Packard',
                    'Gateway') result
FROM suppliers;
```

Which is equivalent to this pseudo code

```
if (supplier_id == 10000)
{
    SELECT 'IBM'
} else if (supplier_id == 10001)
{
    SELECT 'Microsoft'
} else if (supplier_id == 10002)
{
    SELECT 'Hewlet Packard'
} else
{
    SELECT 'Gateway'
}
```

**EDIT**: Performance of the NVL and DECODE for the NULL replacement was measured by users and it seems to be almost equal.

I personally advice to use NVL when you need to do the NULL replacement, because it's a bit more expressive.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this in a couple minutes when the system lets me (too soon to accept, apparently). No need for the elaboration. That was my understanding of what `DECODE` did. The two looked equivalent to me and I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at some Oracle NVL function examples and explore how to use the NVL function in Oracle/PLSQL.

For example:

```
SELECT NVL(supplier_city, 'n/a')
FROM suppliers;
```

The SQL statement above would return `'n/a'` if the `supplier_city` field contained a null value. Otherwise, it would return the `supplier_city` value.

Another example using the NVL function in Oracle/PLSQL is:

```
SELECT supplier_id,
NVL(supplier_desc, supplier_name)
FROM suppliers;
```

This SQL statement would return the `supplier_name` field if the `supplier_desc` contained a null value. Otherwise, it would return the `supplier_desc`.